# A joke riddle about a serious thing

Tags: riddle, wordplay, language

My prefix means to work together, and when written in full words, it means something almost rectangular.
My infix is *neves semit thgie semit enin* in Italy, and when written in full words, it means something usually rectangular.
My suffix is indivisible, and when written in full words, it can end its own suffix.
My whole, despite not being Phileas Fogg, unfortunately managed to travel the whole world in less than 80 days (but it's rarely written in full words).

(Note: The question can be a bit inappropriate, apologies to those who feels offended.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is

> Covid-19

**My prefix means to work together, and when written in full words, it means something almost rectangular.**

> Co means to work together. When written in full is almost rectangular (Colorado state in the US)

**My infix is neves semit thgie semit enin in Italy, and when written in full words, it means something usually rectangular.**

> 9*8*7 = 504 in roman numerals is DIV in reverse is VID. When written in full words could VIDEO, which are usually rectangular.

**My suffix is indivisible, and when written in full words, it can end its own suffix.**

> 19 is a prime number. When written in full is nineteen, (MISSING EXPLANATION)

**My whole, despite not being Phileas Fogg, unfortunately managed to travel the whole world in less than 80 days (but it's rarely written in full words).**

> Covid-19 went on world tour in less than 80 days, and is rarely written as coronavirus (full words)

Comment: Great job. Beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: Great and quick! The only thing you missed is that rot13(gur ntr bs avargrra hfhnyyl raqf gur "grra" fgntr, naq GRRA vf bs pbhefr fhssvk bs AVARGRRA).

Comment: Actually, the "full words" of the whole would be rot13("Pbebanivehf qvfrnfr").

Comment: @LannyStrack That doesn't seem "full" either. There are several items in the Pbebanivehf family.

Comment: @user253751 Actually, what I should have written is that rot13("pbivq-19" vf fubeg sbe "pbebanivehf qvfrnfr 2019"). That would have been the complete answer. But my main point was that the words in the solution (rot13("vf eneryl jevggra nf pbebanivehf (shyy jbeqf)") are incorrect.